# How define the dependency injections in spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, dependency-injection

I try to create a spring web application with spring-boot. My first problem that the dependency injection does not work for me. This is the [article](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) what I followed.

I created an Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

then I made a controller:

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    @Autowired
    WfExampleDao wfExampleDao;

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        wfStartDao.insert(null);
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

my exampledao:

```
public interface WfExampleDao {
    public void insert(WfExample wfExample);
}
```

and my implementation of interface:

```
@Component
public class WfExampleDaoImpl extends JdbcDaoSupport implements WfExampleDao {

    private Logger logger;

    public WfExampleDaoImpl() {
        this.logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    }

    @Override
    public void insert(WfExample wfExample) {
        logger.info("Insert is not implemented yet.");
    }
}
```

my gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.6.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

war {
    baseName = 'gs-rest-service'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-rest-service'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '4.3.11.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.3.11.RELEASE'

    compile 'commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:1.4'
    compile 'commons-pool:commons-pool:1.6'


    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '1.5.6.RELEASE'
    providedRuntime group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat', version: '1.5.6.RELEASE'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '1.5.6.RELEASE'
}
```

What I expect: When I open the /greeting page, log will appear, but I got this in the begining of the `gradle bootRun`:

> 2017-09-12 10:47:56.058  WARN 7545 --- [           main]
>   ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered
>   during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'greetingController': Unsatisfied
>   dependency expressed through field 'wfExampleDao'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'hu.example.dao.WfExampleDao'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

I don't know why can not find the dependency. As I read, I don't have to create an `applicationContext.xml` because the bootRun figures out the dependencies.

Thanks for the advices in advance!

Comment: `WfExampleDao` become  `WfStartDao` latter in its interface implementation.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake

Comment: @Crabime I corrected it, thx!

Comment: Are other classes in same package or child packages of `Application` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At default, springboot will scan all components in child packages of Application class. You didn't specify the component scan so make sure all classes are in same package or child packages of `Application`.

Comment: You are right, they were not in the same package. Thx! :)